# In Java code, how can I extract text of a random html page?

Tags: java, jsoup

I solved this way:

```
String url = ("http://www.repubblica.it/economia/finanza/2011/10/27/news/la_fine_dell_incertezza_solleva_le_azioni_bancarie_in_borsa_alle_italiane_mancano_15_miliardi_di_capitale_met_di_unicredit-23967707/");

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 2000);

Elements body = doc.select("body");

String s=body.text();

System.out.println(s);
```

I still have another problem. I just want the main text without a title. Who can help me?

---

I need an algorithm that extracts the text from websites. I want this text is clean from the tags, classes, etc. and I want that this algorithm can be applied to any web page.

For example for [this page](http://www.repubblica.it/economia/finanza/2011/10/27/news/la_fine_dell_incertezza_solleva_le_azioni_bancarie_in_borsa_alle_italiane_mancano_15_miliardi_di_capitale_met_di_unicredit-23967707/)

I need the main text:

> MILANO - Il tanto atteso responso sui fabbisogni di patrimonio delle
>   maggiori banche europee è arrivato. L'Eba (l'Autorità di controllo
>   bancaria europea) ha stabilito la necessità, entro giugno 2012, di
>   ricapitalizzare per ben 106,5 miliardi di euro per i 30 gruppi europei
>   più importanti. Sui 70 gruppi considerati, invece, il deficit
>   patrimoniale è di 160 miliard...............

For [this page](http://www.repubblica.it/economia/finanza/2011/10/27/news/chrysler_spinge_gli_utili_del_lingotto_fiat_contro_consob_sulla_lettera-23995026/)

I need the main text:

> TORINO - Effetto Chrysler sui conti Fiat. Il Lingotto archivia il
>   terzo trimestre con utili in crescita a 17,6 miliardi (8,4 nello
>   stesso trimestre 2010). Più che triplicato l’utile della gestione
>   ordinaria che passa da 256 a 851 milioni. Due terzi arrivano da
>   Detroit che................

Thanks

Comment: you can try apache http commons

Comment: Two things: Firstly, please use a self-answer if you've arrived at a solution of your own and mark as accepted, don't use your question to do this. Secondly, if you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [boilerplate](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) library.

Another option would be to explore [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), which will index content in a meaningful way.

Note that defining "main text" is largely impossible. If you know the site you can try to understand their template and make some assumptions. Doing it across *random* sites is difficult, which is where something like boilerpipe/tika come into play.

Answer (score 2):

I've just discovered [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and it looks just perfect for what you want

Seems that something along these lines will extract that text from "div_Id"

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.repubblica.it/economia/finanza/2011/10/27/news/la_fine_dell_incertezza_solleva_le_azioni_bancarie_in_borsa_alle_italiane_mancano_15_miliardi_di_capitale_met_di_unicredit-23967707/").get();
String text = doc.body().id("div_Id").text()
```

I'm not the expert on this lib, but indeed is way more easier that httpCommonsClient